# Emberjs a good way to handle async ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am quite new to emberjs and would like to know what is the best way to deal with something like the following:

View:

```
{{#if model}}
  <p>I exist</p>
{{else}}
  <p>Login first</p>
{{#if}}
```

In my JS:

```
App = Em.Application.create({});

App.MyRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(){
    $.get("some/ajax/call",function(data){
        controller.set('model', data)});
    }
  }
}};
```

In the above example setupController will complete and flashes the `<p>Login First</p>` and when the data arrive form the ajax call it changes to `<p>I exist</p>` I try to do this in a model the result is the same.

Currently I use some jquery to hide and unhide stuff to get around this but I don't think is the best way? seems abit brittle to me.  any advice will be really helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `afterModel` hook to perform any checks. This hook fires with the model that was returned by jQuery, but before `setupController`.

```
model: function() {
  return $.get("some/ajax/call",function(data){
      return data;
  }
},

afterModel: function(model) {
  // if model is not valid 
  // transitionTo another route etc
}
```

Note that you just return the `data` from the jQuery `promise`. Ember understands that when a promise is resolved with a value it is the `model`.

Comment: Thx. I changed what I have done. Using after mode to render another template if the model is empty. So I dont need any ugly hide show code.